# Mongolian Mongo Username/Password

Tags: mongodb, node.js

I'm trying to use [Mongolian](https://github.com/marcello3d/node-mongolian) in one of my projects and I'm using MongoHQ to host the databases however it requires a user/pass to access them. I couldn't find any docs on how to use authentication with Mongolian (it was hard to find any with mongo-node-native even). Is there a way to do this or will I have to fork mongolian and add this myself (I'd rather not since I'm very new to mongo and I don't really understand the mechanics of the driver)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never used Mongolian but using the driver, when you connect to the database, you have to call `db.authenticate`.

```
var db = new mongo.Db(dbname, new mongo.Server(host,port, options)),
    collection = null,
    getCollection = function (callback) {
      db.collection(options.collection || defaults.collection, function (err, col) {
        collection = col;
        callback(null, col);
      });
    };

db.open(function () {
  if (err) {
    throw new Error("Error connecting to " + _url);
  }

  if (username && password) {
    db.authenticate(username, password, function () {
      getCollection(callback);
    });
  } else {
    getCollection(callback);
  }
});
```